# operator overloading multiple operands C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have coded NumberS class, it is just for demonstration. I overloaded the operator+. It is OK when applying the operator with 2 operands, but applying with more operands producted undefined result. The code is below

NumberS.h

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class NumberS
{
private:
    long long number;
    void assign(long long);
public:
    NumberS();
    NumberS(long long);
    void operator=(string);
    NumberS& operator+(string);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os,NumberS numb)
    {
        os<<to_string(numb.number);
        return os;
    }
};

int main()
{
    NumberS number(5);
    number="10";
    cout<<number<<"\n";//print out 10
    number=number+"12";
    cout<<number<<"\n";//print out 22
    number=number+"5" +"6";//<-----   wrong result occured here, I want it to be 33
    cout<<number<<"\n";
    getchar();
}
```

NumberS.cpp

```
#include "NumberS.h"

NumberS::NumberS()
{
    number=0;
}
void NumberS::assign(long long numb)
{
    number=numb;
}
NumberS::NumberS(long long numb)
{
    assign(numb);
}
void NumberS::operator=(string str)
{
    assign(stoi(str));
}
NumberS& NumberS::operator+(string str)
{
    NumberS s;
    s.operator=(str);
    s.assign(number+s.number);
    return s;
}
```

the undefined result occured at the line **number=number+"5" +"6";**, I expect the result to be 33
please help me to get it to the right way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NumberS::operator+` returns by reference, but you're returning `s`, it's a local variable and it'll be destroyed when get out of `operator+`, the returned reference is always dangled. After that any dereference on it leads to UB, anything is possible.

For your case return-by-value would be fine.

```
NumberS NumberS::operator+(string str)
{
    NumberS s;
    s.operator=(str);
    s.assign(number+s.number);
    return s;
}
```

BTW: Most compilers give warning for this case, such as [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/lBk0hT81XEcUVTpI):

> ```
> prog.cc:54:12: warning: reference to stack memory associated with local variable 's' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
>     return s;
>            ^
> 1 warning generated.
> ```

Comment: I got it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
NumberS& operator+=(string s)&{
  NumberS num=std::move(s);
  this->assign(number+s.number);
  return *this;
}
friend NumberS operator(NumberS lhs, string s) {
  lhs += std::move(s);
  return lhs;
}
```

Comment: You meant `friend NumberS operator+(...)`. ?